# How to rewrite url in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite my url like this with .htaccess :

**From** : http://www.uuuuu.com/category/yop-2015/

**To** : http://www.uuuuu.com/2015

Only for the category `yop-`

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/yop-(.+)$ http://www.uuuuu.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
add_action( 'init', 'example_add_rewrite_rules' );
function example_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%category_name%', '([0-9]*)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '([0-9]*)$', 'index.php?category_name=yop-$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```